# Meteor mup deploy fibers error

Tags: meteor, node-fibers

i get the following error when i try to mup deploy

```
Building Started: /Users/../.......
```

Started TaskList: Deploy app 'meteor' (linux)

[195.30.108.227] - Uploading bundle

[195.30.108.227] - Uploading bundle: SUCCESS

[195.30.108.227] - Setting up Environment Variables

[195.30.108.227] - Setting up Environment Variables: SUCCESS

[195.30.108.227] - Invoking deployment process

[195.30.108.227] x Invoking deployment process: FAILED

```
-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
les/fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
npm ERR! argv "/opt/nodejs/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! fibers@1.0.5 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.5 install script 'node ./build.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the fibers package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./build.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs fibers
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls fibers
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /opt/meteor/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm-debug.log
-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
 > ./bcrypt: npm install due to binary npm modules
bindings@1.0.0 node_modules/bindings

nodeunit@0.9.1 node_modules/nodeunit
└── tap@0.7.1 (inherits@2.0.1, buffer-equal@0.0.2, slide@1.1.6, deep-equal@1.0.1, yamlish@0.0.7, nopt@3.0.6, mkdirp@0.5.1, difflet@0.2.6, glob@4.5.3, runforcover@0.0.2)

> fibers@1.0.5 install /opt/meteor/tmp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
> node ./build.js

make: Verzeichnis »/opt/meteor/tmp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build« wird betreten
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o
make: Verzeichnis »/opt/meteor/tmp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build« wird verlassen
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using node version v4.4.7, but meteor build run on v0.10.40 or lower.

You can use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) for change your node version.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem.

The issue was related to meteor version and `mup`
As my meteor was 1.2.1 and my mup 1.3.1, needed to change in `mup.js` to use older docker `"kariahq/meteord"` image

```
  docker: {
      // change to 'kadirahq/meteord' if your app is not using Meteor 1.4
      image: 'kadirahq/meteord'
      //image: 'abernix/meteord:base'
    },
```